# Add dataframe name in new column when using bind_rows R

Tags: r

I feel like this should be obvious but I can't seem to find any information on this!

I would like to use bind_rows to combine two dfs, and have a new ID column created with the names of the df that data was from.

```
new_df <- bind_rows(apple_df, tiger_df, .id = "???")
```

So new_df$id should contain "apple_df" and "tiger_df" as values.

I've tried .id = "src", .id = "id" but nothing seems to work. The closest is .id = "id" but I get the index number as a result.

I also want to avoid overcomplicating this as much as possible. It seems like it should be a basic feature to have .id = "nameofobjectsbeingbound". Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Use `lst` to put them in a named list and then use `bind_rows` to combine the dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- bind_rows(lst(apple_df, tiger_df), .id = 'id')
```

Example -

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 2:6, b = 12:16)
new_df <- bind_rows(lst(df1, df2), .id = 'id')
new_df

#    id a  b
#1  df1 1 11
#2  df1 2 12
#3  df1 3 13
#4  df1 4 14
#5  df1 5 15
#6  df2 2 12
#7  df2 3 13
#8  df2 4 14
#9  df2 5 15
#10 df2 6 16
```

Comment: that was lightning fast! thanks! i had not heard of `lst` before, so thanks!